# How can I get direction vector from normal vector in 3d?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Lets say I have normal vector $(x,y,z)$ how can I get direction vector from it?

In $2d$ is simple as far as I know just change $\pm$ sign of one of two values but how it works in $3d$? Thank you.

Comment: Any vector of type $\vec{(x,y,z)}\times \vec{(a,b,c)}$ will be orthogonal to $\vec{(x,y,z)}$ if $\vec{(a,b,c)}$ is not parallel to $\vec{(x,y,z)}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $3$-dimension, a plane is perpendicular to a non-zero vector.

If $x$ is non-zero,
$(-y, x, 0)$ and $(-z, 0, x)$ spans the plane.

I leave the case where $x$ is zero to you.

Answer (score 0):

You are sure that you haven't
$$x=y=z=0$$
so, at least one of them is non-zero.

assume it is $ z $.

you look for $ (a,b,c) $ such that

$$ax+by+cz=0$$

there are two solutions representing the  vectors directors of the plane normal to your initial vector.

you can take
$$\vec{u}=(0,z,-y)$$
and
$$\vec{v}=(z,0,-x)$$

You can also choose
$$\vec{v}=(x,y,z)\land \vec{u}$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a procedure one can use in computer programs and such.

Let's say $V = (v_x, v_y, v_z)$ is some nonzero vector ($v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2 > 0$), and you want to find a basis where the third unit vector is in the same direction as $V$.  There are infinitely many such (mutually orthonormal vector triplets), we just want to find one, regardless of which one.

First, normalize the vector to unit length, by dividing its components by its Euclidean norm ($\sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2}$).  Let's call this $Z = (Z_x, Z_y, Z_z)$.

Pick the component with the largest magnitude, negate it, and swap it with the component with the smallest magnitude.  For example, if the third basis vector was $\left(\frac{2}{7}, -\frac{3}{7}, \frac{6}{7}\right) \approx (0.286, -0.429, 0.857)$, you end up with $\left(-\frac{6}{7}, -\frac{3}{7}, \frac{2}{7}\right) \approx (-0.857, -0.429, 0.286)$. Let's call this $(P_x, P_y, P_z)$.  It cannot be parallel to $(Z_x, Z_y, Z_z)$, but it is not necessarily perpendicular to it either; we can fix that by applying one step of [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process):
$$X = P - \frac{P \cdot Z}{Z \cdot Z} Z = P - (P \cdot Z) Z$$
(because $Z$ is already an unit vector, $Z \cdot Z = 1$), and then normalizing $X$ to unit length:
$$\begin{aligned}
c &= P_x Z_x + P_y Z_y + P_z Z_z \\
x &= P_x - c Z_x \\
y &= P_y - c Z_y \\
z &= P_z - c Z_z \\
n &= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} \\
X_x &= \frac{x}{n} \\
X_y &= \frac{y}{n} \\
X_z &= \frac{z}{n} \\
\end{aligned}$$
Because of the construction of $P$, $n$ is always positive, and we get an unit vector $X = (X_x, X_y, X_z)$ that is perpendicular to $Z$.

That gives us the last and first unit vectors of our basis.  The middle one we can get simply via cross product, $Y = Z \times X$, i.e.
$$\begin{aligned}
Y_x &= Z_y X_z - Z_z X_y \\
Y_y &= Z_z X_x - Z_x X_z \\
Y_z &= Z_x X_y - Z_y X_x \\
\end{aligned}$$
And thus, the basis set $X, Y, Z$ is complete, with $Z \parallel V$.

Note that a transformation matrix to that basis to Cartesian $x$, $y$, and $z$ axes, i.e. rotating $V$ to $z$ axis, is $\mathbf{R}$,
$$\mathbf{R} = \left[ \begin{matrix}
X_x & X_y & X_z \\
Y_x & Y_y & Y_z \\
Z_x & Z_y & Z_z \\
\end{matrix} \right] = \left[ \begin{matrix} X & Y & Z \end{matrix} \right]^T$$